# How to show Erlang call stack?

Tags: erlang, stack, call

I need to debug some module in foreign system. The module has public function `foo()` - how can I know place (module and function name)
from which foo() given module was called? I mean stack of calls.

I cannot stop system, all work I can do by reload this module (but with some debug info).

```erlang
-module(given).
-export(foo/0).

foo() ->
    %% here is my debug - and
    %% i need here(!) known about unknown_module:unknown_foo!
    ok.

---
-module(unknown_module).
..

unknown_foo() ->
    given:foo().  %% see above
```

Comment: I hav modify my example, please comment

Comment: Please note that in a case like your example above, the call to given:foo() is a tail call - this means there will be no trace left of it on the stack (per definition). If you need to do this sort of debugging, you should learn about tracing in Erlang.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a simple trick:

```
Trace = try throw(42) catch 42 -> erlang:get_stacktrace() end,
erlang:display(Trace)
```

Comment: Nice trick but when I tried I got compilation error `erlang:get_stacktrace/0: deprecated; use the new try/catch syntax for retrieving the stack backtrace`.

Comment: Newer variant is `try throw(42) catch _:_:Stk -> Stk end,`

Answer (score 4):

This might work:

```
where_am_i() ->
    try throw(a)
    catch throw:a:Stacktrace ->
            Stacktrace
    end.
```

Except that it doesn't work for tail calls.  For example, given these two functions:

```
foo() ->
    where_am_i().

bar() ->
    X = where_am_i(),
    {ok, X}.
```

I get these results:

```
4> foo:foo().
[{foo,where_am_i,0},
 {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
 {shell,exprs,6},
 {shell,eval_exprs,6},
 {shell,eval_loop,3}]
5> foo:bar().
{ok,[{foo,where_am_i,0},
     {foo,bar,0},
     {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
     {shell,exprs,6},
     {shell,eval_exprs,6},
     {shell,eval_loop,3}]}
```

That is, I can only see `bar`, since `foo`'s call frame has been left already when `where_am_i` is called.

Answer (score 2):

```
io:format("~s~n", [element(2, process_info(self(), backtrace))]).
```

self() can be replaced by any other pid (rpc:pinfo should even work with remote procs). This helps if you cannot even modify the source or beam.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for doing this:

```
format_stack_entry(S) ->
    {Module,Fun,Arity,[{file,File},{line,Line}]}=S,
    io_lib:format("{~p,~p,~p,[{file,~p},{line,~p]}",[Module,Fun,Arity,File,Line]).
stacktop([Top|_]) ->
    Top.
ancestor(N) ->
    {_,Stacktrace}=erlang:process_info(self(),current_stacktrace),
    ancestor(N+1,Stacktrace).
ancestor(1,S) ->
    format_stack_entry(stacktop(S));
ancestor(N,[_|T]) ->
    ancestor(N-1,T).

info(Format)      -> io:format(lists:concat([ancestor(2),Format,"\r"])).
info(Format,Args) -> io:format(lists:concat([ancestor(2),Format,"\r"]),Args).
```

Lists is a custom module in the system.  Use your foo module instead.