# How to get caller module name in included module?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How to get caller module in included `MyApp.MyUniversalModule` and get by on field_name argument?

```
defmodule MyApp.MyUniversalModule do
  def gen_and_check_unique(changeset, field_name) do
    token = random_string()
    # MyApp.MyQueryableModule |> Repo.get_by(field_name, token)
  end

  def random_string(length \\ 8) do
    :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.url_encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.MyQueryableModule do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  import MyApp.MyUniversalModule

  schema "items" do
    field :name, :string
    field :token, :string
  end

  def changeset(model, params) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name), ~w())
    |> gen_and_check_unique(:token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: While this answer answers the title of the question, your code is incorrect in several places as @stephen_m's answer points out.

---

Although you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252004/erlang-call-stack) get the call stack at runtime and extract the calling module from that, it's going to be inefficient and is generally not recommended. The idiomatic way in Elixir would be to use macros and the `__using__` hook.  [Ecto uses the same method for `Repo`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/9f512edebfa78265f61b74fbd8dbb9dd116b5a7e/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L83) as well as many other modules.

Basically, you define all the functions you want to be injected into the caller module inside a quote in the `__using__` macro. In this case, that would look something like (untested):

```
defmodule MyApp.MyUniversalModule do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      def gen_and_check_unique(changeset, field_name) do
        token = random_string()
        __MODULE__ |> Repo.get_by(field_name, token)
      end

      def random_string(length \\ 8) do
        :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.url_encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in `MyApp.MyQueryableModule`, change:

```
import MyApp.MyUniversalModule
```

to

```
use MyApp.MyUniversalModule
```

You may want to not pollute the calling module with `random_string`, in which case you can do (again untested):

```
defmodule MyApp.MyUniversalModule do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      def gen_and_check_unique(changeset, field_name) do
        token = MyApp.MyUniversalModule.random_string()
        __MODULE__ |> Repo.get_by(field_name, token)
      end
    end
  end

  def random_string(length \\ 8) do
    :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.url_encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I think there are two separate issues here:

#### 1. Repo.get_by (To get a schema from a piece of data)

To get the `MyApp.MyQueryableModule` which is a schema, you can use the
Repo.get_by/3 function as follows:

```
alias MyApp.MyQueryableModule

defmodule MyApp.MyUniversalModule do
  def gen_and_check_unique(field_name) do
    Repo.get_by(MyQueryableModule, [{field_name, random_string()}])
  end
end
```

### 2. Casting a changeset

In this code,

```
  def changeset(model, params) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name), ~w(token))
    |> gen_and_check_unique(:token)
  end
```

you seem to be trying to return a `Ecto.Schema.t` where normally a `Ecto.Changeset.t` would be expected. Also, I'm not sure but you might be doing two things in one in this function (`applying changes` and `get_by` ??), I generally keep my changeset functions for just validation changes and applying changes. Finally, `Ecto.Changeset.cast/4` is deprecated in favour of `Ecto.Changeset.cast/3` See [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4).